# Spring shell blocks tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I added spring shell to project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

tests began to hangs and never ends. After stop I see in logs

```
2020-02-22 20:00:14.271  INFO 9812 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-02-22 20:00:14.933  WARN 9812 --- [           main] org.jline                                : Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information)
2020-02-22 20:00:15.229  INFO 9812 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [192.168.1.10:5672]
2020-02-22 20:00:15.312  INFO 9812 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#4c32d208:0/SimpleConnection@608c36a6 [delegate=amqp://admin@192.168.1.10:5672/, localPort= 65404]
2020-02-22 20:00:15.401  INFO 9812 --- [           main] c.umbrella.app.BackendApplicationTests   : Started BackendApplicationTests in 12.969 seconds (JVM running for 14.251)

Process finished with exit code -1
shell:>
```

The problem reproduces when I run tests from IDE and mvn.
How to avoid problem with tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution, it needs to add next properties to each test:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
    InteractiveShellApplicationRunner.SPRING_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_ENABLED + "=false",
    ScriptShellApplicationRunner.SPRING_SHELL_SCRIPT_ENABLED + "=false"
})
```

Answer (score 5):

In Spring Shell 2:

```java
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.shell.interactive.enabled=false")
```